# Why can't I move anything to my adopted storage SD card?

Tags: adoptable-storage

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite WiFi (gta4xlwifi) running Lineage OS 19, rooted with Magisk. I have just inserted a brand new 256GB SD Card and formatted it as adoptable storage. The SD card is nearly empty (i.e. lack of free space is not an issue). When I set it up, it showed me the following screen that was supposed to allow me to copy all my files to the SD card, which is exactly what I wanted to do:

[image]

So, I tapped the "Move content" button, and... nothing happened. The button flashed a bit, indicating that my tap was registered, but the device just remained at this screen and as far as I can tell, no files were moved. Similarly, I went into the app list in Settings and tried to change the storage location  of one of my apps, which took me to a screen similar to the one above with a "Move" button. Again, tapping this button registered the tap but did nothing and simply remained on the screen.

Notably, I actually *can* forcibly move apps to the adopted storage using Titanium Backup's "Move to Adopted storage" option under special features. However, Titanium Backup doesn't have any way for me to move my non-app-associated files (i.e. the 39.44 GB in the above screenshot), so this doesn't get me what I want.

So, it seems like my tablet has allowed me to set up adopted storage and then staunchly refused to move anything onto it (except *via* Titanium Backup). Am I missing something? Is there something I have to do to make the "Move content" button actually work? How can I convince Android to let me actually *use* my SD card to store files?

Comment: Samsung usually won't provide adoptable-storage at all, might be LineageOS developers haven't properly enabled that feature? *'adb shell pm set-install-location 2'* and install new app. check which disk space has changed with `df`

Comment: @alecxs Interesting, so maybe there's some hardware limitation or quirk that Lineage OS doesn't know about? As for installing apps, like I said, I can force move them with Titanium Backup, so I don't care as much about a solution for that as I do about moving everything else.

Comment: you can figure it out by installing new app